# How to track inbound HTTP traffic using Plesk 10.4.4?

Tags: traffic, bandwidth, plesk

I am running Plesk 10.4.4 on a Debian 6.0 server. The outbound traffic is being tracked but the inbound http traffic seems to be 0 at all times, i.e. looking at the `DomainsTraffic` and `ClientsTraffic` the `http_in` column is always 0.

Is this a setting that I have missed? I've had a look and cannot find anything. How do I get Plesk to track the inbound HTTP traffic?

I have already made sure that Home > Tools & Settings > Server settings had 'Include in the traffic calculation' set to 'inbound and outbound traffic', yet this does not solve the problem.

Apache allows inbound traffic to be logged using `%I` in the log format, is there a way to get Plesk to add the `%I` to the log and then use that in bandwidth calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Plesk grabs HTTP stats from access_log file of Apache. As I understand there is no way to put incoming HTTP traffic in access_log. Even if I upload huge file to the server, access_log would only report a size of server response, but not a size of incoming request. So incoming HTTP traffic cannot really be tracked through Plesk. You would need some additional  tool for that.

Comment: Using `%I` you can add incoming traffic to an access log in Apache, the issue seems to be that there is no way to have Plesk access it. Is there somewhere to specify the format for the access log?

Comment: You can redefine LogFormat in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, but I think it will simply break Plesk parser at the moment. You probably need to ask for %I support in the Plesk forum.

Comment: Thank you Sergey. I was asking if there was somewhere to set the format for the parser. Shame it doesn't seem to be possible... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you manually run:

```
server_pref -u -traffic-direction both -count-type byte -stat-keep 3
```

Where 3 tells it to keep the stats for three months; pick whatever you prefer here.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work for HTTP. FTP, SMTP and IMAP/POP3 seem to work fine, it's just HTTP in that doesn't work.